# Flutter Driver Location Track by admin

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, push-notification

I'm planing to develop an app in flutter that tracks the drivers device location and record that location into firebase, the app successfully connected to the firebase server. when I click on a button in the app will send the current location to the firebase and also google map is integrated in my app.
My requirement is

1. Install app on driver mobile. Register driver details and login. firebase database collect the data with deviceid.
2. Install the app on Admin mobile. he can login as admin. in his dashboard all drivers listed. he click on the particular driver he can able to view driver correct location.

My problem is how to send a request to the driver mobile that the app may be not opened. when the request came on driver mobile app will automatically send current location details to the firebase database. How I do this? Is firebase push notification is possible? any one have any idea please help

Comment: To send a notification to a user that doesn't currently have the app open, you'll indeed need to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging. I recommend reading the document and searching for a tutorial, and posting back when you have a more concrete question implementing this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your message. I ma new in flutter . is it possible to run a function when a notification is received with Firebase Messaging ?

Comment: Yes. See https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview and https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you very much Mr Frank. I found the code and it works fine. When notification receive background process successfully update firebase database.   firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hai Frank I have one more question. When the admin send a push notification to the particular user, the user received sucessfully. I don't want to show the Notification to the user. only communication will happened. don't inform the user via push notification. what I mean is when the notification show the user he can understand we are tracking him. so how to block this?

Comment: To send a message that is not automatically shown, don't include a `notification` property in the message. If you only include a `data` block, the system won't auto-show the message and instead (only) deliver it to your application code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hai Frank. thank you for your comment. Push notification send successfully and its working. I am using FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler). its working fine in android but in iOS its not working. you have any idea regarding this issue

Answer (score 2):

To send a notification to a user that doesn't currently have the app open, you'll indeed need to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging.

To get started with this in your app, see the [overview](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview) documentation for Cloud Messaging in FlutterFire, as well as the documentation on its [usage](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage).